# How to control <abbr> element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to fix or dictate the height and width of the abbr element in the following instance? Thank you.

```
<html>

<div class="date"><abbr class='timeago' title=$date></abbr></div>

</html>
```

Comment: `<abbr>` is a standard visible inline element like `<span>` - you can just use normal css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with dictate? This would be my solution:

```css
abbr
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: 5px; /* I guess the best value in this case to play with */
}
```

```html
<div class="date">This <abbr class='timeago' title=$date>Date</abbr> is important.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display:inline-block` into your attr element in order to 'see' it.

```css
abbr {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="date">
      <abbr class='timeago' title=$date></abbr>
  </div>
</html>
```

Editing it is just like styling any other element (you just have to insure your element is 'visible' or 'has content' first).